# Android Eclipse Interstitial Ads not showing for an error

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, google-play-services

This is my code

```
package mypackegename;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private InterstitialAd interstitial;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the interstitial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx");

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    displayInterstitial();
  }

  // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
  public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the code snippet of Android manifest

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
```

I also import the google play services and my app is running but interstitial ads are not showing and an error is showwing, the error message is following:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma from frame with URL http://imasdk.googleapis.com/js/core/bridge3.1.65_en.html#goog_694420715. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after your create Interstitial Ads method

```
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
              public void onAdLoaded(){
                   displayInterstitial();
              }
    });
```

this way

```
public class Interstitial extends Activity {

      private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

      /** Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
      private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_juego);

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
              public void onAdLoaded(){
                   displayInterstitial();
              }
    });

      }

      // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
      public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
          interstitialAd.show();
        }
      }
    }
```